# Reinforcement learning, reward in skip frame

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Since in skip frame, the same action will be executed the next 4 frames. What should I do if during the the skip frame period, rewards are given? I mean in the game API, if skip frame is used, is the reward the accumulated reward during the skip frame period or only the reward at first frame during the skip frame period?

Answer (score 1):

In the original implementation from the [Mnih et al.](https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v518/n7540/full/nature14236.html)  paper they return you a cumulative reward over the skipped frames.